# Photoshop CC (OS x) not cropping tight to edges

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2015

Photoshop CC isn't cropping tight to edges of images in my canvas.

When using the marquee tool and selecting an area, then going to Image > Crop, there is still canvas remaining outside of the selected area

It only seems to be happening when pasting an image and trying to crop it with this method

[image: Screenshot]

This screen shot shows my image (the block of blue colour) which I pasted into a new canvas but has transparent edges. (The large black area is just my photoshop app background, left in to show the transparency)

[image: Marked out area]

This shows the marked out area which I have then cropped, but the transparent area remains after performing this action.

What setting do I need to change to make the crop work to my selected area, not with this unwanted white space/padding?

Comment: Have you checked your feather settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere near your selection options, you will have Feather and it should be set to 0px for a clean cut, if set higher, you will get the effect you mention. It's like the smoothness of a brush but for selections.